# Skip multiple iterations in Scala for loop

Tags: scala, for-loop, iteration, skip

```
for ((c,i) <- collection.zip(0 until collection.length)) c match ???
```

I want to iterate over a collection with indexes. And if **c** matches some pattern i want to skip multiple iterations(demands on what it matched).

Is there a way to do this or a better way to iterate like this?

Comment: Firstly, `collection.zipWithIndex` will give you the values that you want to iterate over. But you need to provide a bit more detail on what exactly you want. It might be that `collect` or an `if` in the `for` can do what you want, but likely to need  custom recursive function for more complicated skipping.

Comment: Im trying to parse string for reverse polish notation. So im iterating over every character in string.
For example: If current character is digit im extracting all further digits to get the full number and skipping iterations over those digits.
In recursive approach i faced a problem with obtaining previous character(for unary operators) without making code looking too bad.

Comment: A recursive routine is very definitely the right approach for a parsing application, but, again, hard to give more help without some more concrete code in the question. You should also consider using a parsing package. (I use Scala parser combinators, but I gather there are better solutions available now)

Comment: Note that `for` is NOT a loop in **Scala**, is just sugar syntax for `map` and `flatMap`, thus the answer to your direct question is: not possible. - You may use a `while` loop but that level of mutability and imperatively are usually not idiomatic in **Scala**. - Rather, you may consider turning the `String` into a `List[Char]` and use a tail-recursive method.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez there's no need to convert to `List[Char]`, especially in view of `List[Char]` almost certainly being massively less efficient than keeping it a `String` and tracking the index.

Comment: @LeviRamsey I prefer to optimize the readability and maintanibility of the code over performance (especially without any kind of formal benchmarking, SLAs definition & statistical analysis. Easy code is easier to refactor if you actually end up needing to make it more efficient. A tail recursion over `String` with index is prone to making a mistake and accessing a wrong index. Anyways, OP may also first tokenize the `String` into a `List[Token]` so another point to using `List`